# Wordpress - GD Star Rating - Set Rating after wp_insert_post

Tags: wordpress, rating

is it possbile to rate the new post (with admin account) after this?

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post, $wp_error );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/rating-programmatically-a-new-article-with-gd-star-rating) of the Wordpress support forum, what you should do is something like this:

```
function set_rating($post_id, $vote) {  // $vote = 0..10
  $admin = get_user_by('login', 'admin');
  if ($admin !== false) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
    $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    gdsrBlgDB::save_vote($post_id, $admin->ID, $ip, $ua, $vote);
  }
  return $admin;
}
```

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_User could not be converted to string in .../...../db.php on line 467 :/

Comment: @Peter I've edited my answer to solve the problem; apologies for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a hook after that happens. First write a function and then this:

```
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'set_star_rating');
function set_star_rating() {
    global $post;
    $post = ...
}
```

There is also `save_posts` hook which happens while you're saving the post and is better [documented](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post).

Comment: I found nothing for GD Star Rating in this documentation. Can you give me an example?

Comment: OK...what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I'd love to help you, but I can't find ANY documentation or API of this plugin. But I see you're adding posts yourself so you don't even need to set up hook. You have ID so you just have to send the rating to the post ID. Now if there were documentation this function would probably be there :P

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful for doing some custom development based on GD Star Rating Plugin. Find my functions to 'save post like', to get 'like count for a post' and to 'check whether current user liked a post'. This is working for custom Post Types as well.

```
/**
 * Function to save post like
 * @param type $post_id
 * @param type $user_id 
 */
function save_post_like($post_id, $user_id) {

    $ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
    $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    if(has_user_liked_post($post_id) == 0)
        gdsrBlgDB::save_vote_thumb($post_id, $user_id, $ip, $ua, 1);

}

/**
 * Function to check if user like the post
 * @global type $wpdb
 * @global type $table_prefix
 * @param type $post_id
 * @return type 
 */
function has_user_liked_post($post_id) {

    global $wpdb, $table_prefix;

    $userdata = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id = is_object($userdata) ? $userdata->ID : 0;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table_prefix . "gdsr_votes_log WHERE vote_type = 'artthumb' AND id = " . $post_id . " AND user_id = " . $user_id;
    $results = $wpdb->get_row($sql, OBJECT);

    if (count($results))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

/**
 * Function to get total Likes of a Post
 * @global type $wpdb
 * @global type $table_prefix
 * @param type $post_id
 * @return type 
 */
function get_post_like_count($post_id) {

    global $wpdb, $table_prefix;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table_prefix . "gdsr_data_article WHERE post_id = " . $post_id;
    $results = $wpdb->get_row($sql, OBJECT);

    if (count($results))
        return $results->user_recc_plus;
    else
        return 0;
}
```